# GLib: propagate warning errors through UI

Tags: c, user-interface, error-handling, glib

I'm making a framework in ANSI C using GLib. The GError struct provides a nice method to manage errors, but I would like to modify my print_error macro, to propagate the error, for example, to the UI.

'print_error' macro is the following one:

```
#define print_error( error ) \
g_assert(error != NULL); \
g_warning("%s", error->message); \
g_error_free(error);
```

How can I modify it for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the macro as-is, but [register a handler](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Message-Logging.html#g-log-set-handler) which displays the error in your UI.  How you do that depends on your application, and how you want your error to be displayed.

```
void my_log_handler (const gchar *log_domain,
                     GLogLevelFlags log_level,
                     const gchar *message,
                     gpointer user_data) {
  // Message contains the error string... put it in your UI here
  popup_error_dialog_or_whatever (message);
}
```

How exactly to send the data to the UI depends on your code, what toolkit you're using, how you want it to be displayed, etc.

Actually, I wouldn't quite keep the macro as-is--[I would put it inside of a do...while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Everything works fine and GLib are really amazing ;-)